# iText 5 numeric list items. How to right align the numbers

Tags: itext

Using a numbered list in iText 5. The list item numbers are left aligned. ie they look like:

```
 9.  Hello line 9
 10. Hello line 10
```

What I would like is:

```
 9.  Hello line 9
10.  Hello line 10
```

I cant find a parameter or method to right align the numbers as per the second example. None of the examples I have found have numbers that go above single digits. I have the official book but no help there either.

Does anyone know how?

Thanks,
Murray

Comment: You're asking for something that isn't supported, which explains why nobody is answering. It would be a nice-to-have though.

Comment: Thanks Bruno. I thought that might be the case but I wanted to make sure. Thanks for your work, iText is great!